# Should I inform the current employer that I am about to resign within 1-2 weeks since I have signed the offer letter and waiting for visa?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, new-job, job-change, resignation

I have signed the offer letter from a company based in UAE (United Arab Emirates) and have sent them my documents for visa process since they are sponsoring. Now, I am confused that whether I should inform the current employer or not because once the visa and ticket arrive I will have very few days or maybe a day to inform them. I have to hand over the projects.

I am perplexed. I don't know what to do. I have heard stories of employers rescinding on offers (rare but possible.)

Comment: Isn't this specified in your contract?

Comment: What about your notice period? Didn't you tell your prospective employer what your notice period is? It's never good not to work notice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a contracted notice period, then you're bound to honour it or risk repercussions to your reputation and perhaps legal action.

If you don't have a notice period then you should wait until you have the actual ticket, because this gives you some reassurance that the new employer has invested in you and is unlikely to change their minds.